# Are there badges or extra reputation points awarded for milestone answers?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges

Is there or will there be a special award, badge, or event for site-wide milestone answers, comments, or questions?

> For example, the person who has the 100,000th accepted answer to an ELU question might get some special acknowledgement or reputation points.

Or the person with the one millionth up vote, might have some showcase of their profile, questions, or responses.

In other contexts I've seen the Xth visitor to a site rewarded; this type of thing remains a mainstay of radio shows to promote the station.

If the answer is no, I'd be interested to know the rationale for why.

*I could for instance understand if the goal of this site was quality rather than quantity; i.e. promotions may drive traffic at the expense of quality.*

Comment: Since the rep and achievement system measures *indivudals*, it is generally designed to encourage (=reward) things which *individuals* can productively work towards. Even if the overall goal of SE were quantity, then the system would reward users for their *individual* question or answer count. Individual users have little to no control over whether they post a milestone Q or A, because that is driven by the *aggregate* behavior of *all* the users on the site. A user could work towards a milestone for months only to be sniped by a drive-by anon user who  *happened* to post just the right time.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DanBron.  I simply thought that the large numbers of questions asked and answered deserved some type of recognition or celebration even.  Based on the negative rating, I'll add this to my list of bad questions.  Fear not, this may the last time I get to ask one...

Comment: Minnow, not that it really matters,  but I didn't downvote you. And FYI, on the main site a downvote means "This is a bad question", but on Meta, it simply means "I disagree with or do not want the proposal in this question implemented". In other words, no reason to feel bad about downvotes on Meta.

Comment: Ah, that is highly informative.  I was concerned that the question itself was poorly worded or otherwise not worth even asking.  <br> It does then beg the question: would a series of questions that are 'disagreed with' lead to being banned from asking questions in the meta forum?

Comment: Minnow, I'm not sure, but I don't believe so. I've never seen that happen, anyway.

Comment: I'll admit that I ended up here serendipitously through another question.  Most of the posters are seasoned veterans in the forum or mods, so I imagine their reputation is so astronomical it would take a miracle of serial incompetence to have their postings get them banned.  Either way, I'll rest easy and get back to my cyber-shopping like the other good denizens.

Comment: There are gold badges for 100 upvotes, and for 10,000 views.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange already has badges for *milestone* achievements.

- There's a *gold badge* for a ***great question*** which has earned 100 upvotes

https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/great-question

- A *gold* badge for ***famous questions*** which have attracted 10,000 visits

https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/famous-question

- There's also a *gold* badge for a ***great answer***, once again the answer must receive 100 upvotes.

https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/great-answer

- There's a gold badge for ***being legendary***. This means a user has earned 200 reputation points for posting great answers at least 150 times.

https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary

By clicking on the links you'll see how rare these achievements are on EL&U. I doubt very *very* much that a single answer will ever receive a million upvotes. Or any user will post 100,000 answers—*yikes*! :)

Comment: I was referring to _site-wide_ milestones, not individual achievements for which I agree there are many badges.  Perhaps milestone is not the right word for the collective?

Comment: Oh, in *that* sense, sorry I misread your question. It also looks like Dan Bron got the wrong end of the stick too: *A user could work towards a milestone for months only to be sniped by a drive-by anon user who happened to post just the right time.* That's how I interpreted his comment, but I can see it the other way too. A user answering hundreds of questions in order to get to the 1,000,000th one, to be pipped to the post by a "nobody".

Comment: Considering the above scenario, which I'm sure would cause a lot of "grief", it would be a terrible proposal.

Comment: Your points are well-taken.  The context of this was not so much to reward a random user, but to celebrate the collective wisdom and efforts of the group who answer so many questions.  A collective reward/recognition towards a larger body of acheievement.

Comment: @Minnow Our "reward" will be the [Winter Bash 2014](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5374/hats-are-coming) :)

Comment: @Mary-LouA Looking forward to it as a first timer!